# Как нужным мне способом закрасить кнопку по нажатию в WPF интерфейсе?

Tags: wpf, xaml

Если коротко, у меня необходимость в том, чтобы по нажатию кнопки background этой же кнопки красился в нужный цвет, и так же оставалась в этом цвете, ведь в моём интерфейсе это важно. Уже пробовал сделать это несколькими способами, но нужным образом никакой из способов не сработал. Использовал IsPressed, но он закрашивал кнопку лишь на момент нажатия. Также хотел сказать, что желательно сделать это через триггеры. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Ну как бы где-то все равно нужно хранить это состояние "кнопка была нажата - держи цвет". Так что где-то придется создать свойство для хранения состояния, на которое и реагировать триггером. Это может быть DependencyProperty или свойство во вьюмодели (INPC). А также есть вот такая кнопка ToggleButton, где "хранить состояние" в самом дизайне кнопки.

Comment: @vitidev Спасибо за ответ, обязательно попробую

Comment: @vitidev Не знаете ли вы каких-нибудь триггеров по нажатию на ToggleButton?